# Which is the bestway to get input without "\n" in C?

Tags: c

Which is the bestway to input without "\n" in C 
and some easyway.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: simply string input without \n.

Comment: `echo -n "Input without newline" | ./prog`

Comment: Are you expecting the input string in one line?

Comment: Colon, I'm having a very hard time understanding what you are asking for. Do you mean that you want to type the input, but not have to press ENTER? Or do you mean that you want to read a string from stdin, but not have the `'\n'` character in your buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets`, then remove the `'\n'`

```
char buf[SOME_VALUE];
size_t blen;

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) /* deal with error */;
blen = strlen(buf);
if (blen == 0) /* your system is strange! */;
if (buf[blen - 1] == '\n') buf[--blen] = 0;
else /* fgets "returned" an incomplete line */;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char ch;
ch = getchar();
while( ch != '\n' )
    ch = getchar();
```